Minimizing linear function with constrains on coefficients
Question:
I am faced with minimizing a specific sum:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^{L} a_i x_i $$
$L$, $x_i$ and $K$ are given.
So the question is reduced to choosing proper $a$.
Constrains on $a$:

$a_1$ = 1.
$a_i = a_{i-1} + 1$ or $a_i = 1$ (for $i>1$)
$a$ contains 1 exactly $K$ times.

For example:
$$ 1x_1 + 2x_2 + 3x_3 + 1x_4 + 2x_5 $$
$$ 1x_1 + 2x_2 + 1x_3 + 2x_4 + 3x_5 $$
are valid for $K = 2$, $L = 5$
My approach:
Checking every possible solution by building sequences defined by constrains on $a$ is slow.
Is there a faster solution?
The problem seems to be connected to linear programming, but the restrictions on $a$ make me unable to come with a solution on my own.
Hints appreciated.

Solution in $O(KL)$
With some work this problem can be solved in $O(KL)$.
Beforehand, I recommend reading D.W's answer to get some ground on the problem.
Formula
It can be shown that:
$$M[K,L] = \min\{M[K-1,L'] + \sum_{i=L'+1}^L (i-L') x_i \mid L' < L\}.$$
Let us define some functions:
$$A(i)= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sum_{k=i}^L x_k \text{ if } i \le L \\\\
0 \text{ if } i \gt L
\end{cases}$$
$$B(i)= \begin{cases}
\displaystyle\sum_{k=i}^L (i-k+1)x_k \text{ if } i \le L \\\\
0 \text{ if } i \gt L
\end{cases}$$
$$S(a, b) = \sum_{i=a}^b (i-a+1)x_i = B(a) - B(b+1) - (b-a+1)A(b+1)$$
All of the above can be computed in $O(1)$ after calculating prefixes.
For some $C \ge 2$ (counting from $1$):
$$f(R) = M[C-1, R]$$
$$g(R) = M[C, R]$$
Then:
$$ 
\begin{align} 
g(R) &= M[C, R] \\
&= \min\{M[C-1,R'] + \sum_{i=R'+1}^R (i-R') x_i \mid R' < R\} \\
&= \min\{f(R') + S(R'+1,R) \mid R' < R\} \\\\
&= \min\{f(R') + B(R' + 1) - B(R+1) - (R-R')A(R+1) \mid R' < R\} \\\\
&= \min\{f(R') + B(R' + 1) + R'A(R+1) \mid R' < R\} - B(R+1) - R*A(R+1) \\
\end{align}
$$
Let us say:
$$t_{R'}(x) =f(R') + B(R'+1) + R'x$$
Finally:
$$g(R) =\min\{t_{R'}(A(R+1)) \mid R' < R\} - B(R+1) - R*A(R+1)$$
Method
Now we will minimize $min$ function complexity.
To achieve this, we will build a function $T$ consisting of minimal $t_{R'}$ at coressponding ranges.
Building $T$
a) It is useful to hold $T$ ($t_{k}$ functions) in a structure that can remove elements fast at the begging and at the end. Like deque. The reasons for this will become apparent in the later part.
If $R=2$, $T$ consists of only one function - $t_{1}$
Let us consider adding $t_{k}$:
We visit every function from left to right, until we encounter one that is crossed by $t_{k}$. We can replace every function on the left of the crossing point with $t_{k}$ and shorten the range of the crossed function.
Reason for this:
$R'x$ part of $t_{R'}$ grows by every $R'$, slope of the function changes.
Let us denote $P$ as the crossing point of $t_{k}$ and $T$.
Assume that $t_{k}$ is bigger than $T$ up to $x$ of $P$. As it is bigger, it has to approach $P$ from the top. That means that $t_{k}$ has a smaller slope constant than any part of $T$ left to $x$ (as they get greater). That is a contradiction; every next slope constant is bigger, yet the new $t_{k}$ one is smaller.
Change of slope also implies that $t_{k}$ is minimal at only one range.
We can implement this by traversing our structure from the left, removing elements unitl we encounter a function that has a common point with $t_{k}$. Then updating the ranges of these two in regard to a crossing point.
It can happen that we will remove a lot of functions this way, yet in the full building process we won't remove more than $L$ parts. Hence updating $T$ once is amortized $O(1)$.
Searching for R
On this stage, we have a required part of $T$ built.
As $R$ grows, $A(R+1)$ becomes smaller, so we do not need to start searching every time from the beggining, rather from the previous result.
What's more, we can even discard functions from the right of the found value, as the next values won't appear there. That is when a) becomes useful.
Lenght of the $T$ structure is no greater than $L$, so finding all $L$ takes $O(L)$.
Conclusion
Let's consider some $K \gt 1$. For every K we need:

$T$ to be built - $O(L)$
Calculate values of every $L$ - $O(L)$.

We also precompute prefixes once in the $O(L)$ time.
So the overall complexity is $O(K(L+L)) = O(KL)$

There is an efficient algorithm to solve this, using dynamic programming. Let $M[K,L]$ denote the smallest possible value of this sum, for a particular value of $K,L$.  Then notice that $M[\cdot,\cdot]$ satisfies the following recursive relationship:
$$M[K,L] = \min\{M[K-1,L'] + \sum_{i=L'+1}^L (i-L') x_i \mid L' < L\}.$$
Why?  Consider where the last 1 appears, in the optimal solution.  It must appear at some position, call it $L'$, where $L' < L$.  Then $M[K-1,L']$ counts the smallest possible value of the sum for indices $i=1..L'$, and $\sum_{i=L'+1}^L (i-L') x_i$ counts the value of the sum for indices $i=L'+1..L$.
So now you can fill in all entries of $M[1,\cdot]$, then all entries of $M[2,\cdot]$, and so on, in increasing order of $K$, using the above relation.  This gives an algorithm whose running time is $O(KL^3)$.
In fact it can be improved to $O(KL^2)$ time by precomputing prefix sums for $x_i$ and $ix_i$.  Specifically, we precompute prefix sums for the sequence $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_L$.  We also precompute prefix sums for the sequence $x_1,2x_2,3x_3,\dots,Lx_L$.  This allows us to compute $\sum_{i=\ell}^u x_i$ and $\sum_{i=\ell}^u i x_i$ in $O(1)$ time, for any interval $[\ell,u]$ of indices.  Notice that $\sum_{i=\ell}^u (i-L') x_i = \sum_{i=\ell}^u i x_i - L' \sum_{i=\ell}^u x_i$, hence we can also compute that sum in $O(1)$ time.  Consequently, each term in the $\min \{ \cdots \}$ expression above can be computed in $O(1)$ time.  Since there are $O(L)$ such terms, this means we can compute $M[K,L]$ in $O(L)$ time.  There are $O(KL)$ entries of $M[\cdot,\cdot]$, and each entry can be computed in $O(KL)$ time, so the total running time is $O(KL^2)$.

Could you please expand on achieving $O(KL)$? We can eliminate sum complexity in the $min$ function by precomputation, but we are still left with checking cells $L' < L$. This leaves us with $O(KL^2)$.

@Umbra, Good catch.  My mistake.  The overall running time is $O(KL^2)$ as you say.  I've edited my answer to correct the error.  Thank you for the careful reading.

Actually, this problem can be solved in $O(KL)$. I have written an answer to the question. You may find that interesting.

You can solve the problem via integer linear programming as follows.  For $i\in\{1,\dots,L\}$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,L\}$, let binary decision variable $b_{ij}$ indicate whether $a_i=j$.  The problem is to minimize $\sum_{i=1}^L a_i x_i$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{j=1}^L b_{ij} &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,L\}$} \tag1\label1 \\
\sum_{j=1}^L j b_{ij} &= a_i &&\text{for $i\in\{1,\dots,L\}$} \tag2\label2 \\
a_1 &= 1 \tag3\label3\\
b_{ij} &\le b_{i-1,j-1} &&\text{for $i>1$ and $j>1$} \tag4\label4\\
\sum_{i=1}^L b_{i1} &= K \tag5\label5
\end{align}
Constraints \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} enforce $b_{ij}=1 \iff a_i=j$.
Constraint \eqref{3} is your first constraint on $a$.
Constraint \eqref{4} enforces $a_i\not= 1 \implies a_{i-1}=a_i-1$.
Constraint \eqref{5} enforces $a_i=1$ exactly $K$ times.
